# Не работает хранимка при вызове в коде. Просто в SQL MS Studio работает норм| MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Вызываю хранимую процедуру в коде. Падает ошибка 500 на вызове процедуры.

```
 SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@date", date);
 var data = _db.StrongData.FromSqlRaw("GetDataByDow30 {0}", 
  param1).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Сигнатура вызова вроде правильная. Такая же везде в проекте и работает норм.

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataByDow30]
 @date Date
AS
 select
 s.Id,
 s.Ticker,
 s.Ask,
 s.WinOne,
 s.DiffOne,
 s.IAsk,
 s.IBid,
 s.AskTwo,
 s.BidTwo,
 s.AskThree,
 s.BidThree,
 s.Date,
 s.Time
 from StrongData As s
 join IndexData as i On i.DOW30 = 'true'
 where s.Date = @date and s.Ticker = i.Ticker
 order by Time
```

Она же в студии MSSQL

```html
select 
 s.Id,
 s.Ticker,
 s.Ask,
 s.WinOne,
 s.DiffOne,
 s.IAsk,
 s.IBid,
 s.AskTwo,
 s.BidTwo,
 s.AskThree,
 s.BidThree,
 s.Date,
 s.Time
 from StrongData As s
 join IndexData as i On i.DOW30 = 'true'
 where s.Date = '2020/01/08' and s.Ticker = i.Ticker
 order by Time
```

Хардкодил даже дату в хранимке что б точно как в студии. Все равно не работает. Проверял модель. Все поля точно совпадают. В студии нормально работает. При вызове в коде падает

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: в profiler'e MSSQL смотрел, приходят ли входные данные в БД или нет?

Comment: @ДенисМатюшкин Не, не смотрел. Вы имеете ввиду переменная @date?

Comment: @FX_Sektor да, именно ее

Comment: вы в студии работаете от имени того же пользователя, что и в коде? и в студии то вы выполняете запрос из хранимки, или саму хранимку? Саму процедуру выполняете, чего запрос то сам дергать.

Comment: @teran в студии дургаю сам запрос, а в коде уже хранимку. Ок, я попробую в студии вызывать как хранимку. Как попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: под тем же юзером подключитесь только. а то на хранимки надобно права на выполнение давать еще.

Comment: @teran попробыл в студии вызвать процедуру, процедура работает

Comment: смотрите логи, чего гадать-то. Или запускайте отладку, смотрите с какими исключениями падает.

Comment: @teran Спасибо, кароче я включил все виды ексепшенов и заметил что все таки у меня модель неправильная. Можете оставить ответ, я отмечу как правильный.